# Need help to automatic refresh an offline page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hello and good day all,

If I may ask if there any ways that I can use to automatic detect and refresh a page that went offline without any human intervention.I tried to use navigator.onLine() but it seems not working.. Anyone can give suggestion on how to make it happen using javascript or codebehind VB in asp.net framework? Whenever a page that goes offline due to lost connection or something to automatic refresh when the connection is presence or connected... Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Well, if you are offline, you can't access the server. So you need to do this in JavaScript. I would periodically make an AJAX request, and if it fails, then you know that you are offline. Keep retrying until it works, then you know you are online again.

Comment: Use `setInterval` in JS to make AJAX calls which detect connection availability at specified intervals. If the call result is an error, repeat the call process until the page known to be online.

Comment: @SumnerEvans Hello there, thanks for replying..can you please be more specific.. bcoz i am really bad with this **javascript** things.. tried to search for solution from the google so far but none of them work for me as for now..

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Hello sir, I am so sorry since I am very bad at this Javascripts things.. can you please be more specific sir :(